# Compiler reports 0 for sizeof(unit32_t) in Code composer

Tags: c++, code-composer

I am working on C++ based project where i am getting one error for below statement:

**Code:**

```cpp
typedef char pb_static_assertion_UINT32_T_WRONG_SIZE3507__COUNTER__ 
[ ( sizeof ( uint32_t ) == 4 ) ? 1 : - 1 ] ;   // The line giving error
```

**Error:**

```
"C:\Users\tkumar\Documents\LDRA\LDRAunit_C_CPP_9.7.1\trial\inszt_algctivationgateway.cpp", 
line 4330: error #95: the size of an array must be greater than zero"
```

**Reference:**
uint32_t is defined using:

```cpp
typedef unsigned long uint32_t;
```

I have doubt for unsigned long size, anybody here to explain to tell me the reason behind this error ?

Answer (score 3):

The smallest addressable unit (i.e. "char") on the C2000 architecture is 16 bits.

It's a bit unusual these days, but it's allowed. C allows for all kinds of fun CPU architectures past and future does not actually require a "char" to be 8 bits. "Char" could be 9, 10, 11, or even 16 bits like on the C2000.

For the C2000 C compiler, sizeof(char) = 1 and char is 16 bits.
Now you can see why, to be consistent, sizeof(uint32_t) = 2

If it helps, you can think of the C2000 as having 16 bit bytes. So a 32 bit value is two of these big bytes. It does making using 3rd party C libraries on C2000 a little tricky because most people assume uint8_t is available.

I've seen some libraries typedef a uint8_t that is actually a uint16_t but this just hides the problem. PLEASE avoid that. Those fake "uint8_t" can have values over 255 which is bad news for code that assumes it will wrap around!

There's a great write up (not mine) here:
https://faehnri.ch/byte-not-8-bits/

Comment: Yes, the proper assertion is `32 == CHAR_BIT * sizeof (uint32_t)` which will do 8*4 on most architectures and 16*2 on C2000 and in all cases give 32.

Answer (score 1):

1) Code-Composer compiler outputs object in formats called COFF or EABI.  When COFF was selected, unsigned long was 40-bits on for some of the microprocessors at least.  When EABI was selected, it was 32-bits.
2) For some of the TI microprocessors, such as the C2000 series, the smallest addressable word was 16 bits, and sizeof would then output 2 instead of 4 for a 32-bit type.
3) One or the other of these is probably causing your sizeof statement to be returning something other than 4, causing ?: to select -1.  So the array size is less than 0.
4) Don't think you really want an array after a typedef.

Answer (score 0):

The real mayhem here is with the definition and usage of `char` and **byte**, both in the ISO 9899 standard (which makes them interchangeable, mentioning sizes) and vendor (TI) documentation.

In the document "TMS320C28x C/C++ Language Implementation" this horrible mess is politely described as follows:

> **TMS320C28x Byte is 16 Bits**
>
> By ANSI/ISO C definition, the sizeof operator yields the number of
> bytes required to store an object. ANSI/ISO further stipulates that
> when sizeof is applied to char, the result is 1. Since the TMS320C28x
> char is 16 bits (to make it separately addressable), a byte is also 16
> bits. This yields results you may not expect; for example, size of
> (int) = = 1 (not 2). TMS320C28x bytes and words are equivalent (16
> bits). To access data in increments of 8 bits, use the __byte() and
> __mov_byte() intrinsics described in Section 7.5.6.

In fact, **a byte is not made by a fixed number of bits**: can be defined *at will*, somewhere around [1 to 48 bits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte).

From what I see this has roots long in the past, and nothing has changed even if we use it today to express a unit we *believe to be fixed*.
Even **ISO/IEC 80000-13** has arrived too late, defining *their* byte of 8 bits.

[EDIT]

Just for the sake of completeness: note also that working at the assembly level (on the same processor family) **byte definition is different**.
If you refer to [TMS320C28x CPU and Instruction Set](https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/spru430f/spru430f.pdf) any mentioned *byte* unit refers to **8 bits** of storage.

So you can read

> 2.2.1 Accumulator (ACC, AH, AL) [...]
>
> AH.LSB = ACC (23:16) AL.LSB = ACC (7:0)
> [...]
>
> 6.2 C28x Assembly Language Instructions by Function [...]
>
> MOVB AX.LSB, loc16  *Load Byte Value* [...]
>
> **Description**    Load the least significant
> byte of the specified AX register (AH.LSB or AL.LSB) with 8 bits from
> the location pointed to by the “loc16” addressing mode. The most
> significant byte of AX is cleared. [...]

Any further personal comment on this would sound *rude*, so I just stick to plain facts.